# Java - changing data in array

Tags: java, csv

I'm pretty much a complete newbie to java and programming in general. I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

So I have a .csv that I am reading and storing data from (i think in the form of an array?) by using the following. This works fine and is grabbing all the data from the csv.

```
   fo=new File()
   fo.open(filename)
   contents = fo.read()
   fo.close
```

The data that I am grabbing from the .csv is in the form of well positions on a plate e.g. A1, B1, C1, D1 etc. Now is there a way that I can make each of the letters worth a particular value?

For example, A=1, B=2 C=3 etc, and then make this new value multiply by the second number e.g. A1 would become 1*1 = 2 and A2 would become 1*2 = 2 and B2 would become 2*2 = 4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Christian, the JavaScript tag was removed from your post, but I just wanted to make sure you took note of that -- if you don't already know that JavaScript has nothing to do with Java, you probably should.  (The name is the result of an unfortunate marketing attempt to capitalize on Java's success in the mid 90s.)

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) would be a useful tutorial for you. Try to get familiar at looking at [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). The `read()` function returns an int. You might want to look into the [`FileReader` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way that files are read follow this structure:

- Open File using Reader. (using Scanner, FileReader, etc)
- Read data. (Scanner.nextLine() for example)
- Close File Reader. (close)

In your case, one possible approach is to read the data and then if you want an array of values, simply use String.split() method, passing the "," as a delimiter because it is comma separated file. Once you have an array, you make w/e changes you want. In your case, you want to iterate over that array and perform transformations.

However, I would also like to clarify something, because it is kind of implied by your question, that updating the array after you read will **not** update the file. Just wanted to make that clear to avoid confusion.